# Converting Oracle query to MySQL query. all_indexes

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration

I'm trying to convert Oracle query to MySQL query.

My Oracle query has this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc() AS
    iname all_indexes.index_name%TYPE;
    oname all_indexes.owner%TYPE;
BEGIN
    // Do something
END;
```

How can I port this to mySQL, since mySQL doesn't have all_indexes public environment variable?

Comment: all_indexes is a synonym pointing to a view and not a "public environment variable"

Comment: all_indexes is view not variable. use string type instead of pointing column type

Comment: That's not a query - that's a stored procedure. And [`ALL_INDEXES`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1096.htm#REFRN20088) is not an environment variable - it's a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a varchar datatype

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE iname varchar(50);
  DECLARE oname varchar(50);

    // Do something
END;
```

---

You can query an information_schema.statistics to obtain names od indexes

```
Select * 
From information_schema.statistics
```

Demo:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88321/1

Comment: Yes, but "iname" has value set from "all_indexes.index_name%TYPE;". I need to get this value on mySQL too.

Comment: You can query information schema tables i appended an example to the answer